# Sending Zip folder over Python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, server, zip, client

So for some reason this code is not properly working for sending a zip folder from the client to server.  on the server side if I use "f = zipfile.ZipFile("platformIO.zip")" I get the error "ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path", and if I use "f = open("platformIO.zip", "wb")" no error is thrown but the received file is corrupt and won't open.

I have read every similar to question to this and cannot find a solution.

Client:

```
import socket
import time


# Configure wireless connection with server (board on leg)
HOST = "192.168.4.1" # change to server ip address
PORT = 5005 # must be same as server

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
print("connected")

user_input = "startup"

while True:
    if user_input == "startup":
        # ask if user wants to send code
        user_input = input("Do you want to send new code?: (y/n)")
        if user_input == "y":
            user_input = "send code"        
        elif user_input == "n":
            user_input = input("Would you like to collect data?: (y/n)")
            if user_input == "y":
                user_input = "receive data"
            else:
                user_input = "startup"
        else:
            user_input == "startup" 
    elif user_input == "send code":
        st = "sending code"
        s.send(st.encode())
        file = "platformIO.zip"
        try:
            with open(file, "rb") as f:
                print("sending file...")
                data = f.read()
                s.sendall(data)
            print("finished sending")
            st = "finished"         
            s.send(st.encode())
            user_input = "startup"      
        except:
            print("Failed transfering <platformIO.zip>, make sure it exists")
            st = "failed"           
            s.send(st.encode())
    elif input =="receive data":
        print("feature not yet implemented")
        user_input == "startup"
    # delay
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Server:

```
import socket
import time
import zipfile
import os

# create server
HOST = "192.168.4.1"
PORT = 5005
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("socket created")

# managing error exception
try:
    s.bind((HOST,PORT))
except socket.error:
    print("bind Failed")

s.listen(1)
print("Socket awaiting mesesages")
(conn, addr) = s.accept()
print("connected")

# awaiting message
msg = "startup"

while True:
    if msg == "startup":
        # receive data from controller
        msg = conn.recv(4096)
        print(str(msg, 'utf-8'))
    elif str(msg, 'utf-8') == "sending code":
        f = zipfile.ZipFile("platformIO.zip", "w")
        #f = open("platformIO.zip", "wb")   
        while True:         
            data = conn.recv(4096)
            print(data)         
            if not data:
                break
            f.write(data)
        print("file received")  
        msg = "startup"
    time.sleep(.1)

conn.close()
```

edit: if I use f = open("platformIO.zip", "wb") and add s.close() inside the writing while loop of the server, I can receive the zip successfully, but then the connection closes and I can't open the zip file until I close the program

```
    f = open("platformIO.zip", "wb")    
    while True:         
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        print(data)         
        if not data:
            break
        f.write(data)
        s.close()
```

Comment: *"I have read every similar to question to this and cannot find a solution."* - which sounds like lot of work but says exactly nothing what you really looked at and tried. The statement is thus useless. Instead of providing useful information you essentially provide an undocumented code dump and an error message as the only information and expects others to figure out how your code is supposed to work and what you might have though when writing the code and how your code is supposed to be used in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help dude.... even if you disregard that statement I provided ample code and even the error message for an experienced python socket programmer to hopefully identify the error.

Comment: *"I provided ample code"* - without any relevant documentation (i.e. you just a code dump) and specifically not any documentation how this code can be used to reproduce your problem by others. For example there seems to be some serial connection involved for some unknown reason - if this is irrelevant for the problem please remove it as you should remove anything which is not needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).